# Cannot login OFBiz 17.12.04: The Following Errors Occurred: following error occurred during login: User not found

Tags: ofbiz

- I download JDK 8u261 x64 for Windows x64 , then set `JAVA_HOME`, set `PATH` environment variable.
- I download https://mirror.downloadvn.com/apache/ofbiz/apache-ofbiz-17.12.04.zip
- I run file `gradlew.bat`
- I run command

```
gradlew cleanAll loadDefault
gradlew ofbiz
```

Running screenshot

[image]

- I go to https://localhost:8443/accounting/control/login

use username: `admin`, password: `ofbiz` (Follow the guide at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Demo+and+Test+Setup+Guide )

But error

[image]

Error message:
The Following Errors Occurred:
following error occurred during login: User not found. How to fix it?

Follow guide at http://ofbiz.135035.n4.nabble.com/Following-error-occurred-during-login-User-not-found-td4706898.html , I run

```
gradlew "ofbiz ‐‐load-data readers=seed,seed-initial" loadAdminUserLogin -PuserLoginId=admin
```

but not success.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows x64,  I run

```
git clone https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/ofbiz-framework.git ofbiz-framework
gradlew cleanAll loadDefault
gradle ofbiz
```

Wait about 40 minutes. Go to https://localhost:8443/accounting use username: `admin` and password: `ofbiz` .

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you got it working by now, here are my notes:

**Install OFBiz with Microsoft Windows 10**

1. Download Java SE JDK

For OFBiz you need the JDK version 8. You can download this from here:

https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot

For Windows 10 in 64 bit select the matching „msi“ file, this is the exact link:
https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u265-b01/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u265b01.msi

2. Execute the downloaded file and install the Java JDK and JRE. Do not modify the default file paths.
   During the installation there will be a window called „User defined Setup“ where you can select the components to install. In there you can specify that the JAVA_HOME environment variable shall be set during the install process. Enable this and select the local disk as the location where you will install the Java JDK.
3. Download the OFBiz ZIP archive
   https://ofbiz.apache.org/download.html
4. Unpack the directory apache-ofbiz-17.12.04 in the zip file. You can rename this directory to e.g. c:\ofbiz
5. Set the environment variables
   You can skip this step, if you selected that these variables shall be set during the installation. If you missed this, you have to set them manually:

Get into Control panel – extended system settings – environment variables, set a new JAVA_HOME variable:
JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_265

Then test whether this variable has been set successfully in a command window:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

After that, add this path to the system path variable:
control panel – extended system settings – environment variables, existing path variable
%JAVA_HOME\bin% (=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_265\bin)
Close these windows again to get Windows to enable this path variable.

Now test the path variable in a new command window:

```
enter java
enter javac
```

If these commands output a lot of explanations, your are ok

6. Install OFBiz
   Open the INSTALL file and follow the instructions in there

a) open a command window in administrator mode
For that right-click on the start button, open search, enter cmd and then select cmd to execute as administrator.
Get into the ofbiz directory you created, e.g. c:\ofbiz

b) enter this command:

```
init-gradle-wrapper (=init-gradle-wrapper.bat)
```

If this does not work, you have to set the script policy to bypass. You can either edit the script or enter on the command line:

```
type init-gradle-wrapper.bat
```

Then enter the last line manually using bypass:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -File gradle\init-gradle-wrapper.ps1
```

c) run gradlew.bat

```
gradlew cleanAll loadAll (=gradlew.bat cleanAll loadAll)
```

Allow this script to download files when queried by Windows

d) Finally start OFBiz by entering:

```
gradlew ofbiz
```

You can make a startofbiz.bat file with this command and generate a link to that from your desktop to restart it conveniantly.

OFBiz will compile and start. When the message OFBiz is started and ready appears, followed by several further messages, it will stop with the prompt :ofbiz.

[image]

7. Run OFBiz
   Open a browser window and enter `https://localhost:8443/webtools (or ecommerce, or catalog)`

The default login is admin, password ofbiz